# Spotfire - row count by group

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a simple list and I'd like to create a calculated column with consecutive numbers by group

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRj3G.png)

I don't know what to do. Please help me

Comment: do you mean that each time the list has e.g. another 'A' you need to restart counting?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

First add a column [RowID] to hold the Row id:

```
RowId()
```

Then identify when the column changes as column [change]:

```
SN(Integer([mycolumn]!=lag([mycolumn])),0)
```

where the function SN() is there to set the first row (which would be null) to zero.
Integer() turns a boolean into 0/1.

Then enumerate the onset of each new value as column [between_group_id]:

```
Sum([change]) OVER (AllPrevious([RowID]))
```

Finally calculate your group id for each new onset of [mycolumn]:

```
DenseRank([RowID],[between_group_id])
```

If you don't want the intermediate columns (apart from [RowID] which is needed because the OVER function does not support function calls):

```
DenseRank([RowID],Sum(SN(Integer([mycolumn]!=lag([mycolumn])),0)) OVER (AllPrevious([RowID])))
```